# django/haml: how to dynamically substitute variable content inside tags

Tags: python, django, haml

```
- for o in options
    {% with po_label=o.name %}
    {% with po_name=o.name|slugify %}
      %label.new-check-radios{for='check_person_q1_{{po_name}}'}
        %input#check_person_q1_{{po_name}}{type='checkbox',name='check_person_q1_#{po_name}'}= po_label
      %div
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
```

This is the generated HTML, using django 1.7.7

```
<input id="check_person_q1_" name="check_person_q1_#{po_name}" type="checkbox">First Option
                                  <div></div>
```

Basically I need to assign dynamic names and ids on the input checkboxes, but because of the {{ }} notation of django I can't seem to be able to do it!

How is this correctly done?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating all the dynamic elements inside the `haml {}` block for the input element and using nested `{{}}` django code blocks:

```
%input{id='check_person_q1_{{po_name}}',type='checkbox',name='check_person_q1_{{po_name}}'}= po_label
```